# Best way to determine when app is foreground

Tags: android

I would like to ask You about best way to determine that my app is currently visible to user (foreground). I know there are two solutions:

1. Using `ActivityManager` but this is very expensive way.
2. Create any `boolean` variable and change its state in `onResume()`
   and `onPause()` of every `Activity`. This solution has one main
   disadvantage additional code to remember about.

Do you know any other, better way? What do you think, whats better and why?

**EDIT**

---

According to my second sollution skywell suggest that we can create an `Activity` where in `onResume()` and `onPause()` we can change state of our `boolean` variable. Every `Activity` in application should extends our new `Activity`. But this idea generate few new problems:

1. We have to duplicate that new `Activity` for every kind (For example `ActionBarActivity`) of needed Activity.
2. We still have to remember about extends correct Activity, it can be problematic in larger teams.

Great explanation of my second solution is provide in DroidAks's post.

Comment: try to find activity with process and process id.if the activity visible the process will be on top.

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar As i said its first solution using `ActivityManager`.

Comment: what about ActivityLifecycleCallbacks?

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar Its second solution which i proposed.

Comment: @ArturSzymański You can create something like `BaseActivity` which extend `Activity` (`AppCompatActivity`) and make all your activities extend this class. It's basically your solution 2, but not that uncomfortable.

Comment: Yes @skywall suggestion will work. Keep the status in global place like singleton. And you can access it from anyware

Comment: @skywall thx it's good idea. It resolving main disadvantage of second solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track whether the app is in foreground or not. This might be the best way.
Check for the states of your app by yourself using Activity.onPause, Activity.onResume methods. Store "visibility" status in some other class. Now  implementat your own Application class as:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{

    public static boolean isActivityVisible()
    {
       return activityVisible;
    }  

    public static void activityResumed() 
    {
        activityVisible = true;
    }

    public static void activityPaused() 
    {
        activityVisible = false;
    }

    private static boolean activityVisible;
    }
```

Now add `onResume()` and `onPause()` in every `activity`

We can use AndroidLifecycleCallbacks to track whether the app is currently visible to user or not. AndroidLifecycleCallbacks were added in API level 14. Hope it helps you.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

Also add in your manifest following code.

```
<application
android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: Its is good explanation of my second solution. But is we mix it with skywall idea, it can be best final way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer made by DroidAks is good, but not good enough. As we all know, having state in `static` variables isn't the prettiest thing to do. Doing that means that You have to remember that You need to manage this state and clean it up. Also, in this case, having `static` variables in `Application` class means that Your classes will be solely reliant on this particular `Application` class. What if You'd like to make a library out of Your code, which would be used in many apps?

Here is my proposal:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private boolean visible;
    public boolean isVisible()
    {
        return visible;
    } 
    //use Application events to manage app visibility state
}
```

While in Your `Activity` code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication)this.getApplication();
        //myApp.isVisible();
    }
}
```

If the above `MyApplication` class implementation was not enough (there may be trouble with setting `visible` to `false` ), then move on to even more proper solution of this problem:

```
public /*abstract*/ class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private boolean visible;
    protected boolean isVisible()
    {
        return visible;
    } 
    //use Activity events to manage activity visibility state
    //for ex.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        visible = true;
    }
}

public class MyConcreteActivity extends MyActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume(); // calls onResume from base MyActivity,
                          // thus always setting visible state properly
        //isVisible();
    }
}
```

Remember to update Your manifest file accordingly.

**EDIT**

---

> We have to duplicate that new Activity for every kind (For example
>   ActionBarActivity) of needed Activity. 
>   We still have to remember about
>   extends correct Activity, it can be problematic in larger teams.

All of above is solved by having an interface, that is passed around to classes requiring functionality of asking the object about its visibility state.

```
public interface Hideable
{
   boolean isVisible();
}
```

If one would like to use Your class, then this class should explicitly have `Hideable` interface as one of its constructor/public method parameters. If You would like to restrict the parameter to extend `Activity` **AND** implement `Hideable` then this generic example (with wildcard usage) is right thing to do:

```
//TODO design new parameter name
public <T extends Activity & Hideable> void myMethod(T iNeedToBeHideableActivity)
```

After seeing such a method, the developer should:

1. Extend one of pre-defined `activities` already implementing this
   interface.
2. Or implement this interface in their own `activity`.
3. Ask You about what exactly is a wildcard.

The requirement of proper behavior is obvious in this case - the interface should announce, whether particular object is visible or not.

PS. This is not a **very** ugly duplication, as each implementation **could** be different in some ways. For example, `Application` class lacks `onDestroy` event, so implementation of `Hideable` interface should be different there.

**EDIT**

---

Improved above suggestion by adding generics.

Comment: Ok sure, we can find many ways (looks different / works little better but idea is still the same ) to improve one of my proposed solutions. Its still the same way but "more beautiful". It still causes problems described in edit of my post.

Comment: Yes, sure second idea is smarter, but there either is an problem. You can't use this solution in for example service. You have to write another one dedicated for service (Because your service don't know about your activities and can't provide them).
Second huge disadvantage is that you can listen only for one kind activity (passed trough method or constructor parameters).

Comment: @ArturSzymański About service: yes, these don't know about your activities, so the right thing to do here is to make them communicate in some android-specific way, and pass visible value. For example, a custom serializer. The interface comes handy here, as it can be implemented in Your serializable object. About second huge disadvantage: I don't understand that. Why You can listen for only one kind of activity, if the wildcard is specified for `Activity` class? That means all kinds of activities obviously (with `Hideable`).

Comment: As i mentioned in first point of my edit, what when our application using few kinds of activity? It leads to multiple inheritance problem.